# Catch axios request and provide mock in e2e test

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, codeceptjs

I'm testing external website with separate server.
I know that server send api request with axios, like this:
`GET https://website.com/api/getData`
Is there a way to catch this request and provide mock data for testing purpose? 
I don't want to change server-side code, my tests are completely separate.

I've tried axios-mock-adapter but it looks like I have to send a request directly from the test to mock it, but that's not what I'd like to achieve.

I'm using codeceptJS with TestCafe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can mock requests sending with the 'axios' library using the [RequestMock](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/mocking-http-requests.html) feature.
RequestMock is a low-level feature and allows you to create mocks for any requests.